# Think time in JMeter per controller

Tags: timer, jmeter

How to user wait time in JMeter Test Plan, so it will wait after every transaction controller?

When adding constant timer/uniform random timer or any other timer, every sampler in the transaction controller are affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [Flow Control Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) with Pause Action instead

I will executed only once for every controller

> The Flow Control Action sampler is a sampler that is intended for use in a conditional controller. Rather than generate a sample, the test element either pauses or stops the selected target.